# Implementing a discrete Markov Chain simulation in c++ with a graphical interface

Tags: c++, markov-chains, markov

I just wanted to know if any one had any pointers for a library or libraries that support Markov modelling and graphical graph representation, as for a project i must simulate a transport model and be able to develop an interface for it too. I am relatively new to c++.

Comment: "graphical graph"? Or "graphical models"?

Comment: Did you checkout **R** ? It is open source and is quite a good statistical tool.

Comment: Yeh srry bout that  graphical model is a more succinct  way to put it i guess

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Boost Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html) as it will simplify all your graph work.  I am unsure if there is a Markov Chain algiorithm (I am looking for one too) but it should be easy to write once you have the graph -- a concurrent monte carlo approach maybe?

[Numerical Recipes](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Numerical-Recipes-3rd-Scientific-Computing/dp/0521880688/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1316080495&sr=8-1) has many algorithm and code in both C and C++.

The [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) tools are all you need to draw graphs.